# Apache not starting even after changing the host

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

[image]I have seen a million videos already about how "easily" solve the Xampp error problem. They all suggest changing in the logs the 80 to 8080, and 443 to 4433. 
But it's not working for me, what should I do???
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See which apps are using your ports using `netstat -anob`

Comment: I tried that, check out the new photo that I added, there is nothing like 8080 or anything

Comment: Did you try running it as an administrator?

Comment: can you post the detailed error logs for apache?

Comment: How can I do that? The admin button is not enabled

Comment: Joshi, do you mean posting it here, on stackoverflow?

Comment: There is nothing in the error log, nothing about today

Comment: How about event viewer?  Try starting Apache and then check event viewer again.

Comment: Actually, I recently changed the location of the XAMPP folder (moved into another place), can this be the root of the problem?

Comment: Could be, you haven't posted the actual error message, just the generic an error occurred message, so it would be impossible for anyone to know. As a principal it is good idea to make one change at a time, otherwise it can be difficult to know what change was the breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the solution of the problem.

I can't believe that such a common problem was not discussed in the tutorials. It's simple. I changed the location of the XAMPP folder and everything has gone astray. Now, I executed "setup_xampp.bat" and followed the instructions, pressing "1" and, refreshing XAMPP.

Just. Like. That.